# Susy Grid 2 / Grid Floats: How to verticle align bottom on a floated element?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, grid-layout, susy-sass

Lets say I have a simple floated grid, made with susy (or anything else). How do I make the contents of one of the columns stick to the bottom of that column?

I tried `verticle-align`, `align-items`, and other combos, but no luck. And since it is made with floats, any time I put `flexbox` on it, it kills the layout of my buttons since they have an icon floated to the right.

What are some correct ways to do this? Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col s2 action-buttons_container">
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light action-button" type="submit" name="action">Hold Ticket <i class="material-icons right">pause</i></button>
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light action-button" type="submit" name="action">Resolve Ticket <i class="material-icons right">check</i></button>
</div> <!--end .col.s2-->
```

`.col` has `float:left` applied automatically which cannot be removed.

CSS I tried

```
   .action-buttons_container {
       position: absolute;
    }
   .action-button {
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
   }
```

Image of my layout
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is *you can't*, though it's maybe a bit misleading. There are ways to make it happen, but not using floats on their own. The `vertical-align` property only changes the alignment of items relative to inline flow, `align-items` only works with flexbox.

Flexbox might be a great option, and could replace floats (even using Susy). Instead of using Susy's `span` mixin, use flexbox with the `span` function for `flex-basis` e.g `flex-basis: span(3 of 12)`.

Your absolute positioning could also work. You'll want `position: relative` set on the overall container (which you did not include HTML for), and then something like this:

```
.action-buttons_container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: span(3 of 12);
}
```

That might need some minor adjustments depending on the grid details you didn't include.